# Move google calendar event to another person calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, move

How to move Google calendar event to another person calendar? I tried with Google move API but Unfortunately I am getting 404 not found error.

reference: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/move

Any Idea on this?

Comment: posible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959576/google-calander-api-move-event

Comment: hey,I tried with same thing in which they suggested.But I am continously getting this error,  {
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound",
        "message": "Not Found"
      }
    ],
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
  }
}

Comment: I upvoted your question because I'm similarly stuck with a 404. But I think you and Luc could both improve your answers here because neither are clear. By the way, if you want an amazing community like StackOverflow to thrive, it would be best to give points to someone who leads you to a resolution. (I see that Luc helped you over the course of *many* comments, and then you accepted your own answer instead of his.)

Comment: The answer for me was this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46429946/470749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`*Solution*`**:-  For Moving Calendar Event from One calendar To another or Change Organiser.

Using ACL API:
Call Acl API with Targeted Email by passing the fields,

```
calendarId: Primary,
scope:{
 type: user,
 value: Source EmailId
}
```

Using Move API:
Call move Api with Source Email by passing the fields,

```
calendarId: Primary,
eventId: "",
destination: Targeted Email Id
```

So It will move to Destination Email Calendar.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To perform move, the authenticated user needs to have at least write access to both, source and target calendars.

Comment: Authenticated User have write and read access for the source calendar by writing scope like   this https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar (read/write access to Calendars) but How to give write access to target calendar ?

Comment: There are two ways. No.1 go to the web UI for the target calendar and share it with write access to the user you want to use for move. The second way is to authenticate as the target's calendar owner in the API and perform an insert of a "writer" ACL through the ACL collection https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert

Comment: Thanks for answer.I tried with https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert  ,to write access to the target calendar ,the calendar event is moving to targeted calendar emailId.after that is it neccessary to use Move API again?

Comment: Yes, you still need the move API to perform the move itself.

Comment: Can you tell me how to perform with move api ? Actually I am trying in Google Console here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/move and after giving write access to Target Calendar then also I am getting same error i.e 404 not Found.

Comment: Hi luc,I have been trying from last two days since I am not able to do it work properly still I am getting same issue only.Please can you point out me a good way to achieve this.

Comment: Hi Santosh, this is really hard to debug with this little information. You could copy-paste the queries from the API explorer showing what you did when you granted the access and what you do when calling the move. Is it possible your target calendar is inside a domain, which has domain restrictions on maximum sharing allowed?

Comment: hello luc,I did it for granting target calendar Access like ,

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/acl
QueryPassed: {
"role":"writer"
"scope":
{
"type":"user",
"value":"TargetdEmailID"

}

}

Comment: hello luc,I did it for granting target calendar Access like ,

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/acl
QueryPassed:

 {
"role":"writer"
"scope":
{
"type":"user",
"value":"TargetdEmailID"
}
}

Response: 200 OK
- SHOW HEADERS -
{

 "kind": "calendar#aclRule",
 "etag": "\"00001456373574183000\"",
 "id": "user:khavekarsantosh91@gmail.com",
 "scope": {
  "type": "user",
  "value": "khavekarsantosh91@gmail.com"
 },
 "role": "writer"
}
Then I checked in Targeted calendar ,here especially all events of source calendar are showing .

Comment: as you told earlier ,we need to Move Api to perform the move itself.so I tried that one like 
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId/move

Query:
calendarId:"SourceCalendarEmailId",
eventId:"h97q426sglc4dfgqt5r1lj0grk",
destination:"TargetedCalendarEmailId"

I tried all this in Google API explorer .Hope you can understand this one.

Comment: This is wrong: { "role":"writer" "scope": { "type":"user", "value":"TargetdEmailID" }. You'll need to log as the target calendar and share with the source.

Comment: You are performing this operation on the wrong calendar. Again, you will need to log in as the targetCalendar's owner and insert an ACL for the target calendar to give write access to the sourceCalendar's owner.

Comment: Thank you luc for your full support.Yes Now I am able to do move calendar event.I will update the Answer.Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Hi luc,I tried with Instant event it is working.same thing I tried with Recurring event but is  giving error as 
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "calendar",
    "reason": "cannotChangeOrganizerOfInstance",
    "message": "Cannot change the organizer of an instance."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Cannot change the organizer of an instance."
 }
}   


How to do same for chnage organiser for  only one instance in  recurring event ?

Comment: It's not allowed to change organizer of one instance only.

Comment: Okay Thank you Luc..we can do it by deleting the one instance and need to create new by making new Organiser.

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way. However, this new instance will not be updated if you make an "all-following" or "all" change on the recurring event.