# Use Google Calendar API to change owner

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have multiple events I am creating in a google calendar using the API via python. Each event has a google meet attached to it.

Once I have created the events I would like to change ownership of the events to another user. This will allow them to act as hosts for the meeting.

I can do this via the calendar website, by clicking the three dots and selecting "Change Owner".

I cannot find any way to do this via the API. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for move API
You can refer this https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move

Comment: Thank you - I have looked at that - it will allow me to move to another calendar I own. However, if I try to transfer to another users calendar, to make them the organiser, I get a permission denied error - not writable to calendar.

Comment: Found this https://stackoverflow.com/q/31959576/5783608 I guess you can't change ownership without owning target calendar.

Comment: Thank you - that is exactly it. I think I can get around the problem, but it is messy. I will need to get each other user to make a calendar and share it with me, and give me write access. I can then "give" them all the events via the API.  Thank you for your time in helping :)

Answer (score 0):

As claimed by the [Events resource documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource):

> creator   >   The creator of the event. Read-only.

> organizer > The organizer of the event. To change the organizer, *use the move operation*. **Read-only, except when importing an event**.

As for the *move* operation, you will have to make a request like this:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId/move
```

Depending on the exact operations you want to make, you might benefit from making use of creating a [service account and performing domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth#perform-google-workspace-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority).

#### Reference

- [Events: move](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move);
- [Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth)
  .